# Python script won't run on the first input

Tags: python

I'm a student and it's only been a few days since I've started python so this question might be really dumb, but my script won't run on the first input.
It's supposed to take and integer input and then print it three times on one line( ex : if input is 25, the printed result should be 25 25 25)

As I mentioned before, it's only been so long since I've started to learn python. I'm probably missing something pretty obvious here, so if anyone could please just nudge me in the right direction, that'd be appreciated. :)

```
if input():
    a = str(input())
    b = int(a,10)
    print('%s %s %s' % (b, b, b))
```

Comment: You're calling input() twice, and Python waits for input for each call. Is that a good enough nudge?

Comment: This...is a very odd constriction. What are you trying to do with `if input():` here? If you remove that line, the rest of code works just fine.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? In 3.x `input()` always returns a string, there's no need to use `str(input())`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do with your code here, but the line `if input()` is misusing the input command. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp as this will help clarify how to use it.

I believe the following code will produce what you want

```
a = input()
b = int(a,10)
if b == 25:
    print('%s %s %s' % (b, b, b))
```